# Add --check-go-version=false to delve debugger

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I use IDEA to debug a go program, but it exited because of the error:

```
Version of Delve is too old for this version of Go (maximum supported version 1.13, suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)
```

How can I add `--check-go-version=false`?

Comment: What version of the Go plugin for IntelliJ IDEA do you use? You can check it under Preferences | Plugins | Installed.

Answer (score 10):

You can add in `launch.json`.

```
example:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "DebugServer",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]
        }
]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it  setting.json

```
{
    "go.delveConfig": {
        "dlvFlags": [
            "--check-go-version=false"
        ]
    },
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
        "GOFLAGS": "-mod=vendor"        
    },
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked! adding to the launch config didn't help in my case

Answer (score 1):

> Upgrade GoLand to 2019.2.2 or newer and the issue will be fixed. This is not a Delve issue, it's caused by us, JetBrains, embedding Delve in the IDE.

[Reference](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1710#issuecomment-538896656)

Comment: The Go plugin is incompatible with the new build found, though.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding in launch.json of visual code

```
"dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]
```